# Producing new connections out of given one

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, connections, holomorphic-bundles

Let $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over $M$ which is a complex manifold. Let $D$ be a connection on it. So $D$ maps sections of $E$ to sections of $T^*M \otimes E$. Let $D'$ and $D''$ be the $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ parts of $D$.

> Are $D'$ and $D''$ in their own right connections?

I believe the answer to this is no. Because $D(a.e) = d(a) \otimes e + a D(e)$ which gives $D'(a.e) + D''(a.e) = d(a) \otimes e + a(D'(e) + D''(e))$

This doesn't give Leibniz rule for $D'$ and $D''$ individually. Am I right?

**Now let $K$ be a Hermitian metric**.

> Then there exits operators $\delta '$ and $\delta ''$ of types $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ such that $D' + \delta ''$ and $D'' + \delta'$ are K-compatible connections.

How do I produce such operators?

Comment: You are exactly correct about $D'$ and $D''$ not being connections on their own: instead of satisfying Leibniz's rule w.r.t. $d$, they satisfy w.r.t. $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ respectively.

For the second part I only have a partial answer. The $D''$ determines a holomorphic structure on $E$ and given a Hermitian metric $K$ and a holomorphic structure, there is a unique $K$-compatible connection $\tilde{D}$ such that $\tilde{D}''$ coincides with the prefixed (0,1)-type operator D''. However, **this will prob. change the holomorphic structure**.

Comment: Hey there, I found this wonderful paper online. 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1693
Corollary 1 in page 15 settles my question. You may have a look.